# why does setFont take so much time?

Tags: java, user-interface, graphics, fonts

I am trying to draw text on my screen this way:

```
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + " 2.2 ");      //debug
    g.setFont(thisfont);
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + " 2.2.1 ");    //debug
    g.drawString("hallo", x, y);
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + " 2.2.2 ");    //debug
    g.drawString("hallo2", x, y2);
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() + " 2.2.3 ");    //debug
```

according to my debug panel the time that's between setting the font and the first drawString getting drawn is the problem (9 secs). here is the text on the debug panel:

```
1406377881939 2.2 
1406377881939 2.2.1 
1406377890799 2.2.2  
1406377890800 2.2.3
```

why does this take so long, am I doing something wrong or is it just that setfont is not working good in combination with drawString?

Comment: how much time is it taking?

Comment: it takes about 5 secs..?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What Operating System, Java version and JVM are you running?

Comment: windows 8.1; java version 7 update 51;

Answer (score 0):

it's a bit uneconomic to create a new Font each time paint() is called (which happens a lot), you could move that to your constructor. and the font should be changed to some orthodox fonts (Arial,Calibri etc)

try `g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 8))`

[read more...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24971336/graphics2d-setfont-heavily-slows-down-the-start-up-of-java-application)