# Graphics2D setfont() heavily slows down the start up of java application

Tags: java, swing, fonts, java-2d

I am making a game by java and it refreshes itself 60 times per second. Every time it executes a loop and I use g2d to draw images and strings. Things work fine if I do `g2d.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 8));` and drawstring and it would be normal, but if I set the font to some "unfamiliar" fonts and do the same thing, the swing would show white screen in the first second of start up then paint everything correctly and it's apparently too slow (2 secs).

I put a jpanel in a jframe and override the paint() method of jpanel to draw everything I need. I've already used `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` in my code.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Window extends JFrame{
    public Window(){
        add(new Board());
        setSize(800,600);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Window();
    }

    private class Board extends JPanel {
        Font font = new Font("Bitmap", Font.PLAIN, 64);

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
            g2d.setFont(font);
            g2d.drawString("This is slow", 220,200);
            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
            g2d.dispose();
            g.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

This is not in a loop but it's very laggy.

http://fontsov.com/download-fonts/bitmap1159.html

This is the cutie font that slows our application down. "Arial" will load blazingly fast. How can I make this less laggy?

Comment: Try it without setting a `new Font`. Have the font cached as a class member, and use _that_ font. See if any different results. Other than that, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to test out

Comment: how many setfonts are you using?

Comment: thanks do you mean I do this in the very first place of my class Font font = new Font("Bitmap", Font.PLAIN, 64);? and g2d.setFont(font); in the paint() method? I tried this and it doesn't work...:(

Comment: Now see the last point in my comment, and the first point in Hovercraft's answer

Comment: just once and drawstring, and it's slow....:( changed "Bitmap font" to Arial and it's blazingly fast

Comment: Thanks you can see the code now

Comment: Thanks for posting code, but again as per my answer, we would greatly appreciate it if you created and posted a [minimal code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise you're forcing us, volunteers, to do this for you. I beg you not to do this. Please read the link.

Comment: Also, never dispose a Graphics object given to you by the JVM.

Comment: Roger that sir! sorry for the misleading code I gave you before..I'm figuring how to use a jlabel

Comment: `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();`  Does it work faster without that?  Note that Swing components inheriting from `JComponent` are already double buffered.  I've seen a lot of solid Swing animations that don't call `sync()` - precious few that do.

Comment: Thanks, actually I don't know what that line means but a few tutorials on the web added that, so I thought it doesn't hurt to add that line. I'll remove it in future:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First and foremost, for best help, create and post your [minimal code example program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for us to review, test, and possibly fix. Without this, it will be hard for us to fully understand your problem.

Consider:

- Overriding `paintComponent` not `paint` to get the advantage of double buffering.
- Avoid using `invokeLater` unless you're sure that the code is being called off of the Swing event thread and you are making calls that need to be on the event thread.
- Put slow running code in a background thread such as that which can be found using a SwingWorker.
- Putting your text in a JLabel, not drawn on a component.
- Draw all static images to a BufferedImage, and displaying that in `paintComponent`. Then draw all changing images, such as your moving sprites, directly in the `paintComponent` method.
- Don't forget to call your `super.paintCompmonent(g)` within your `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method override.

---

**Edit**
A BufferedImage solution could look like,....

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.*;

public class FooFun {

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      ChildClass mainPanel = new ChildClass();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("FooFun");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

abstract class FirstClass extends JPanel {

   private static final int FPS = 20;

   public FirstClass() {
      new Timer(1000 / FPS, taskPerformer).start();
   }

   ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          gameLoop(); //do loop here
          repaint();
      }
  };

  private void gameLoop() {

  }

  @Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
   super.paintComponent(g);
   Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
   paintGame(g2d);
   // Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
   // g2d.dispose();
   // g.dispose();
}

  public abstract void paintGame(Graphics2D g2d);
}

class ChildClass extends FirstClass {
   private static final Font font = new Font("Bitmap", Font.PLAIN, 64);
   private static final int PREF_W = 900;
   private static final int PREF_H = 600;
   private static final String NIGHT_IN_VEGAS_TEXT = "a Night in Vegas";
   private static final int NIV_X = 240;
   private static final int NIV_Y = 130;
   private BufferedImage mainImage;

   public ChildClass() {
      mainImage = new BufferedImage(PREF_W, PREF_H, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
      Graphics2D g2 = mainImage.createGraphics();
      g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
      g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
      g2.setFont(font);
      g2.setColor(Color.black);
      g2.drawString(NIGHT_IN_VEGAS_TEXT, NIV_X, NIV_Y); 
      g2.dispose();
   }


   @Override
   public void paintGame(Graphics2D g2d) {
      if (mainImage != null) {
         g2d.drawImage(mainImage, 0, 0, this);     
      }
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

}
```

---

**Edit 2**
Or with a SwingWorker background thread....

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import javax.swing.*;

public class FooFun {

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      ChildClass mainPanel = new ChildClass();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("FooFun");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

abstract class FirstClass extends JPanel {

   private static final int FPS = 20;

   public FirstClass() {
      new Timer(1000 / FPS, taskPerformer).start();
   }

   ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         gameLoop(); // do loop here
         repaint();
      }
   };

   private void gameLoop() {

   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
      paintGame(g2d);
   }

   public abstract void paintGame(Graphics2D g2d);
}

class ChildClass extends FirstClass {
   private static final Font font = new Font("Bitmap", Font.PLAIN, 64);
   private static final int PREF_W = 900;
   private static final int PREF_H = 600;
   private static final String NIGHT_IN_VEGAS_TEXT = "a Night in Vegas";
   private static final int NIV_X = 240;
   private static final int NIV_Y = 130;
   private BufferedImage mainImage;

   public ChildClass() {
      imgWorker.addPropertyChangeListener(new ImgWorkerListener());
      imgWorker.execute();
   }

   private class ImgWorkerListener implements PropertyChangeListener {

      @Override
      public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent pcEvt) {
         if (pcEvt.getNewValue() == SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE) {
            try {
               mainImage = imgWorker.get();
               // repaint() here if you don't have a game loop running
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
      }
   }

   SwingWorker<BufferedImage, Void> imgWorker = new SwingWorker<BufferedImage, Void>() {

      @Override
      protected BufferedImage doInBackground() throws Exception {
         BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(PREF_W, PREF_H,
               BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
         Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics();
         g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
               RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
         g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
               RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
         g2.setFont(font);
         g2.setColor(Color.black);
         g2.drawString(NIGHT_IN_VEGAS_TEXT, NIV_X, NIV_Y);
         g2.dispose();
         return img;
      }
   };

   @Override
   public void paintGame(Graphics2D g2d) {
      if (mainImage != null) {
         g2d.drawImage(mainImage, 0, 0, this);
      }
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

}
```

Comment: @TonyStark: the 2nd version will show the window quickly, but not the text, not until the image has been created. The advantage of the BufferedImage, is that it won't slow down your animation.

Comment: I will cry out in tears if I don't take yours as an answer, thank you so much for the help...! though, I mean, perhaps, I shouldn't use that font in the first place because java is so strange. the methods are both slow after all...

Answer (score 1):

it's a bit uneconomic to create a new Font each time paint() is called (which happens a lot), you could move that to your constructor.
and the font should  be changed to some  orthodox fonts (Arial,Calibri etc)